# How to lock the scroll view in place?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to lock the scrollView when my segmented Control comes to top of the screen. How can I do this in swift? What's the code of this? How to compute the distance between the top of the segmented control and top of the view controller? It means how can I find the true place for locking scrollView?

Comment: SO is not the place to ask others to write your code for you. Give it a try (Google is a good place to start) and if you run into problems, post the code you have so far, along with a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

After Swift 4.0 it has changed to

```
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

and

```
scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Just flip the scrollEnabled boolean:

```
yourScrollView.scrollEnabled = false
```

To make it scroll again:

```
yourScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
```